# implement lateral navigation in Android API 10

Tags: android, api, navigation, android-fragments, android-fragmentactivity

how to implement lateral Navigation (https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#horizontal-paging) in android 2.3, api version 10?

Because I did download the example provided by Google in the link but it doesn't work in device with api 10, but there are many aplications in google play that have this functionality.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: but there are many aplications in google play that have this functionality, and works in devices with api 10

Comment: "but there are many aplications in google play that have this functionality, and works in devices with api 10" -- that is because the sample code that you linked to, involving the `ViewPager`, works on API Level 10. And 9. And 8. And 7. And 6. And 5. And 4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ViewPager` itself does work on Android 2.3, assuming you are using the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html)'s `FragmentActivity` and `Fragment` classes, so I'll assume the issue you are having with the example is with the tabs. In that case, I would suggest looking over the [Creating Backward Compatible UIs training](https://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/index.html) and specifically the [Creating an Implementation with Older APIs](https://developer.android.com/training/backward-compatible-ui/older-implementation.html) lesson, which goes over implementing tabs in a method that works on Android 2.3 devices.